# How to set memory breakpoint in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging, breakpoints, conditional-breakpoint

Could anyone tell me how to set memory breakpoint in Eclipse (C++)?

for example:

```
int a = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
  if(i == 50) a = 50;

}
```

I want to detect the action when a is assigned to a new value.

I know in Visual Studio we should set memory break point by getting the address of `a` (i.e. `&a`). Is there an equivalent way in Eclipse?

Your help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this helps:
http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/eclipse_documentation/eclipse_c_c++_guide/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/tasks/eclipse_c_c++_guide_cdt_t_add_watch.htm