# How to create a watchpoint for a local variable in Eclipse CDT?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

```
int global = 0;

int main() {
    int local = 0;
    local = 1;
    global = 1;
}
```

I can create a watchpoint for `global` with:

- highlight the variable declaration
- Run -> Toggle watchpoint

and then the program breaks whenever `global` is modified.

However, if I try this with `local` an error popup appears:

> This operation is unavailable on the current selection. Please select or place the cursor on a field.

GDB allows that with the `watch` command, using hardware watchpoints.

I know that this can give weird results if the stack frame exits, but that is fine.

Eclipse 4.7.0, CDT 9.3, Ubuntu 16.04.

Related: [Setting Memory Breakpoints in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13310693/setting-memory-breakpoints-in-eclipse)

Comment: The referenced Eclipse bug is about JDT (Java) instead of CDT. Search for [watchpoints local](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?longdesc=watchpoint%20local&longdesc_type=allwordssubstr&product=CDT&query_format=advanced) or [watch point local](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?longdesc=watch%20point%20local&longdesc_type=allwordssubstr&product=CDT&query_format=advanced) in CDT instead.

Comment: @howlger thanks, you are right. I did a global search for those terms, and looked into most of those search results. If you find one that is dead on, please answer the question with it :-)

Answer (score 5):

It seems the ***Toggle Watchpoint*** command are **note yet implemented for local variables**: see [Eclipse bug 110016](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=110016):

> [[...]. But the reason why the "Add Watchpoint" feature is 
>   left out is because we currently can't catch the moment when the expression 
>   comes back to scope. So if you set a watchpoint on a local variable and it goes 
>   out of scope, the watchpoint seats in the Breakpoint view and will never be set 
>   on any session again.](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=110016#c1)

As **workaround** you can **manually set watchpoints** for local variables **via GDB in the *Console* view**: see [*Eclipse CDT + GDB: Setting Watchpoints (Juno)*](http://www.fayewilliams.com/?p=1611)