# Eclipse CDT cannot set watchpoint (always disabled - greyed out)

Tags: eclipse, gdb, eclipse-cdt, breakpoints, watchpoint

I cannot set a watchpoint in Eclipse (Photon) using CDT.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13310902/863879) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13310693/setting-memory-breakpoints-in-eclipse) about setting memory breakpoints in CDT, one should be able to set a watchpoint by doing the following:

1. Highlight the variable in the editor, or select it in the Outline view.
2. Click `Run > Toggle Watchpoint`.

However, no matter what I do the menu item Toggle Watchpoint is always disabled (greyed out).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After banging my head against the wall for a while, I finally found [this bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=409779) from **2013**. This is a known issue (apparently for a long time). According to the bug report there are two workarounds:

1. Define [the watchpoint] via the Breakpoints view (i.e. `Drop down menu -> Add Watch point (C/C++)...`).
2. After selecting the text with variable switch active parts to a different view/editor and back. This will enable `Run -> Toggle Watchpoint`

The second workaround worked for me.

For example, if I wanted to add a watchpoint on the variable `x` in foo.c, I would highlight `x` in the editor for foo.c, then switch to another editor (e.g. bar.c) and then switch back to the editor for foo.c.

Comment: Could you explain this a little better, `2. After selecting the text with variable switch active parts to a different view/editor and back` ? Thanks

Comment: @champost - I added an example explanation; hopefully that helps

Comment: This worked for me after opening the Breakpoints view, and messing around the menu options. I don't know the exact steps I took but, suddenly, "Toggle Watchpoint" was not greyed out anymore.